# Application Cache Error

Tags: browser-cache, offline-caching, offlineapps, offline-mode, offline-browsing

I've got this error:
**Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (-1)

    *http://localhost:8080/offline.manifest*
online: NO, event: error, status: idle**

This JSON String show the content of the error:
**({"returnValue":true,"eventPhase":2,"timeStamp":1355923608009,"target":{"onprogress":null,"onchecking":null,"onerror":null,"onupdateready":null,"oncached":null,"ondownloading":null,"status":1,"onobsolete":null,"onnoupdate":null},"type":"error","cancelBubble":false,"cancelable":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"srcElement":{"onprogress":null,"onchecking":null,"onerror":null,"onupdateready":null,"oncached":null,"ondownloading":null,"status":1,"onobsolete":null,"onnoupdate":null},"bubbles":false,"currentTarget":{"onprogress":null,"onchecking":null,"onerror":null,"onupdateready":null,"oncached":null,"ondownloading":null,"status":1,"onobsolete":null,"onnoupdate":null}}) debug.js:34**

I got it with **JSON.stringify(error)**.

OK I have this information. But what can one understand from here???
Where is the problem? How can I solve it?

Thank you in advance.